# Selenium. Cannot click on element

Tags: python, selenium, form-submit

I'm trying to drag some web query results using python and selenium. However, I  have trouble clicking a link/button.

When I run my script, it prompts a message

```
selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: Cannot click on element"
```

I have tried

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div[4]/center/div/p').submit()
```

and

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body[@class='vsc-initialized']/div[@id='wrap']/div[@id='content']/div[4]/center/div[@id='locationSearch']/p[@id='locationSearchButton']').submit()
```

and

```
driver.find_element_by_id('locationSearchButton').click()
```

But none of them can submit the form.
Is there any way to do the submit?
Also, the result area is a textarea, can I use fine_element_by_xpath to retreive the result?

```
# Use IE
driver = webdriver.Ie()
# Open Link
driver.get(r'https://www.freemaptools.com/find-australian-postcodes-inside-radius.htm')
time.sleep(3)
driver.maximize_window()

# Copy Excel content to each line
for i in range(2, r + 1):
    # Clean the input area of form
    driver.find_element_by_id('tb_radius').clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id('locationSearchTextBox').clear()
 
    # Input Radius
    driver.find_element_by_id('tb_radius').send_keys(ws.cell(i, 2).value)

    # Input Search Postcode
    driver.find_element_by_id('locationSearchTextBox').send_keys(ws.cell(i, 1).value)

    # Submit
    driver.find_element_by_id('locationSearchButton').click()

    # Wait 5 seconds
    time.sleep(5)

    # Gain the output postcode
    result = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/center[3]/textarea')
    ws.cell(i, 3).value = result.text

    # back excel file
    if i < r:
        driver.back()
# Save as xlsx file"
wb.save('c:/Code/MappingAreaPostcode.xlsx')
```

Comment: I tried using chromedriver and the command `driver.find_element_by_id('locationSearchButton').click()` works. Try it and see if it works to you too. Try also using the new command syntax `driver.find_element(By.ID, 'locationSearchButton').click()` which you can use by importing  `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`

Comment: Thanks @soundwave, That works for me for the submit in Chrome based environment. However, When I try to use: ```result = driver.find_element(By.ID,'tb_output').get_attribute("innerHTML")``` and ```ws.cell(i, 3).value = result.text```, it prompts me message: ```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'```. I searched that the value is a str and cannot use .text, what other options I can use to retrieve the content and save to my excel file? Thanks.

Comment: ok. I figured it out. I need to remove the '.text' part and it will do the job. All good now Thanks again.